# How to create new YouTube video load feature

Tags: javascript, youtube, onload, youtube-javascript-api

I have noticed YouTube have made a new feature on their desktop website where when a new video is loading it shows a red load bar at the top of the page showing the load status of the video.

I am looking to do something like this but for loading a new page on a website I know I may have to use JavaScript / jQuery.

If you could check out the feature and I would appreciate if someone could help me in doing something like that using CSS and JavaScript.

Doesn't seem very hard, A JSFiddle would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryman.

I don't know if you've found, but I did.

Take a look:
http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/02/loadingbar-js-adding-a-youtube-like-loading-bar-to-your-website/

Best regards.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks a lot. It's really hard to find how it works but this explains it all. They use AJAX instead of CSS.